# Optimal Protection Circuit Configuration for TMC2209 Stepper Motor Outputs

Tags: stepper-motor, circuit-protection, flyback, surge-protection, stepper-driver

I am currently working on a project involving a stepper motor driven by a TMC2209 driver. I aim to implement effective protection for the motor driver outputs. According to section 3.7 of the TMC2209 datasheet https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2209_datasheet_rev1.09.pdf, an LC circuit is recommended for this purpose.

Additionally, I am considering the use of an fly back diodes for further protection. However, I am uncertain about the correct order of these protection elements in the circuit. Here are my thoughts:

**TMC2209 Outputs -> Fly Back -> LC Circuit -> Motor:**
Is this the correct sequence for incorporating both the Fly Back and LC circuit?

**TMC2209 Outputs -> LC Circuit -> Fly Back -> Motor:**
Alternatively, should the LC circuit precede the Fly Back in the connection to the motor?

There are also two other possibilities I am considering:

**TMC2209 Outputs -> LC Circuit Only:**
Is it possible that the Fly Back is not necessary, as the TMC2209 may already include sufficient internal protection?

**TMC2209 Outputs Directly to Motor:**
Lastly, I noticed that the evaluation boards for the TMC2209 from the manufacturer don't seem to use these additional protection circuits. Could it be that neither the LC circuit nor the Fly back is required?

Some context: I have been using the SilentStepStick implementation of the TMC2209, and been damaging them. Thinking some level of protection circuit might be needed.  The idea of using the Fly Back is from https://learn.watterott.com/silentstepstick/protector/.

---

To better clarify the question, here are the two circuits that I have seen used to protect the drive circuitry.

(1) https://learn.watterott.com/silentstepstick/protector/ [image: Flyback Protection Diodes]

(2) [LC Circuit from TMC2209 Data sheet Section 3.7](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2209_datasheet_rev1.09.pdf)  [image: LC Circuit from TMC2209 Data sheet Section 3.7]

- Would it be optimal to put these two circuits in series? And if it is, what is the right order.
- If not, which one would be best to use over the other?

---

It may be useful to show that at the moment I am placing the FlyBack Schottky Diodes in series with the LC Filter Circuit. Below is a quick snippet of my circuit.  Hoping that this prevents any more of my TMC2209 from getting damaged in the future.
[image: Stepper Protection Circuit LC Flyback]

Comment: "Optimal" is an interesting and deep question. Optimal in what sense(s)? Efficiency; immunity to various standards (please specify which); emissions to what levels; component count; component cost; overall cost; layout size; temperature ratings or range; etc.

Comment: By optimal, i had meant driver protection from over surge current/voltage.  Basically, protection from anything that may destroy the motor driver out in the wild.  There is of course, always a concerns about cost, component count and layout size, but i have layed out both these circuits on a my PCB board, and for now, i can live with what i have.  i just want to know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Well, what would the motor driver be exposed to "out in the wild"? How would surge get into the motor connections? Would cross-wiring (motor wires accidentally short to +V, GND, other supplies nearby) or shorting (shorted together) also be a concern?

Comment: What instigated this design, is that I have had to replace a number of TMC2209 stepper motor drivers during development.  This leads me to believe that some force is feeding back to my driver and damaging it.  It may be due to turning off the power supply while the motor is running, or some other operation that i have not accounted.  I admit, i am not a motor expert.  But I'm willing to learn.   My current assumption is that its a over-voltage, or over current problem.  If it is, i would like to know if the circuit i have proposed would mitigate it.

Comment: My first step would be to investigate the failures. Is the supply within safe margins under said conditions? Is the control scheme correct, is motor current being limited?

Comment: Agreed.  will continue to understand the cause of the TMC2209 component failure.  Adding many more test points in and around the circuit, and also (circling back to the posted question) adding footprint for a protection circuit in-case i need it.   The question i have is, is the order of the protection circuit correct?  Especially since its based on two separate recommend protection circuits targeted for this driver.   By your questions, i get the impression, that it may not be common/needed to include these protection circuits, is that correct?

Comment: Well, let me see here. The question as currently phrased, doesn't really sound like what you're after. How about this, you could rephrase it to ask, say -- to review the circuit, is it good, what would it be good for, what not, etc. That's probably the closest nearby question. More useful to you might be, "what are potential failure modes of [this module] in [your development and/or production circumstances]?", but this would most likely be closed for lack of information -- you'll need to provide details of the surrounding circuit, preferably measurements, etc.

Comment: FWIW, I have a sneaking suspicion that your problem is ceramic capacitors, and *supply* voltage overshoot due to hot-plugging (or intermittent connections or loading), ala https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476878/5v-ldo-blowing-up-only-when-testing-current-draw .

Comment: I also suspect that hot plugging/disconnecting the motor could have hurt the driver.   We are far from production.  This is prototype.  And in Prototype, some liberty has been taken on stopping/starting/changing motors.  Not sure, if the circuit above would protect the TMC2209 (stepper motor driver) from that.

Comment: But i am curious to know what other people experiences are with driving a stepper motor.  Do they provide any extra protection between their driver IC and the motor? I been searching for any open source 3D printer schematics, to see if those guys use protection circuit when they drive the stepper motor, but i couldn't find it/ or read.