# Why am I frying an EZ2209 with 24V input?

Tags: arduino

I am setting up an Arduino Nano to run a NEMA 17 motor.

I've wired everything up for the the motor to run.

When first testing, I was using the voltage from the Arduino to power the VM on the [EZ2209](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-EZ-Driver/blob/main/BIGTREETECH%20EZDriver%20Connector/EZDriver%20Connector-Pin.png).

This allowed the motor to barely move but showed me that my code, and wiring were correct.

When I swapped in a 24 V/3 A power supply it instantly fried the driver.

Why would connecting 24 V instantly fry the driver if the driver is rated to 29 V?

VM 24 V from PSU.

Ground - Ground from PSU.

Then the only other pins were VIO - 5 V, ground from the Arduino and pin 6 for the direction pin 7 for step, and pin 8 for enable.

Motor Specs

- Manufacturer Part Number: 17HS08-1004S
- Motor Type: Bipolar Stepper
- Step Angle: 1.8 deg.
- Holding Torque: 16Ncm(22.6oz.in)
- Rated Current/phase: 1.0A
- Phase Resistance: 3.5ohms
- Inductance: 4.5mH+/-20%(1KHz)

Link to Driver (They don't have data for their EZ model, but its the same as their none EZ form factor)

https://biqu.equipment/products/bigtreetech-tmc2209-stepper-motor-driver-for-3d-printer-board-vs-tmc2208

[image]

Comment: What are the specs on the motor? Particularly "phase resistance".

Comment: Please link to a datasheet of the driver. What’s VM?

Comment: VM seems to be Motor supply voltage.

Comment: @hobbs its 3.5ohms

 I added the support page for the driver, I hope that helps.
Yes, the VM is motor supply, so I want to run my Nema off of 24V, which is why I am supplying it to the VM and Ground.

Comment: If you measure your power source with an multi meter, is the 24V accurate with almost no load?

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes its 23.96V with no load, and I confirmed I had the polarity correct.

Comment: @AnthonyTaylor Please add a circuit diagram of how it is all connected so we can be sure.

Comment: This is practically an FAQ on modules like this, and also LDOs. Most likely ceramic inrush, see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476878/5v-ldo-blowing-up-only-when-testing-current-draw

Comment: @TimWilliams  A good addition. I've seen similar happen. "Most likely" MAY be an overstatement (but may not :-) ). Certainly worth checking. I've added that to my answer's "maybe" list with acknowledgement.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "what **MAY** work" answer, as you are not obviously doing anything wrong.
I've not used this IC. After a look through the application note I now want to :-).

A look at the very detailed  [TMC2209 datasheet & application note](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/696/TMC2209_Rev.1.08.pdf) suggests that what you are doing MAY be 'legitimate', but that there may be setup parameters that affect the results.

I suggest trying to "throttle it back" initially.
Suggestions only

- Is this on a PCB or breadboard? If the latter then getting items like R$ & R5 electrically very near where they belong is vital.
- Try a somewhat increased motor supply initially (10V?).
- Try adding a 10k from 5V to Vref - using internal FET Rdson current sensing. (Datasheet page 56). This requires shorting of BRA & BRB to ground BUT you could leave R3 & R5 in initially. This SHOULD make it try and use a vey low motor current (probably :-)) .
- Are R3 & R5 REALLY 0R11 and not maybe a decade lower (stuff happens).
  The table on page 52 gives current vs BRA-BRB values.
  Using 1 Ohms would be a gentle start.
- If I was doing this I'd check continuity of every pin and connection with every other - so you know that ALL the "should be connecteds" are, and that all the "shouldn't be's" aren't. This can be done with a meter set to continuity beeper range, and the time taken is acceptable compared to the annoyance of another dead driver.
- Tim Williams in a comment said:

> *"This is practically an FAQ on modules like this, and also LDOs. Most likely ceramic inrush, see:
> [5V LDO blowing up only when testing current draw](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476878/5v-ldo-blowing-up-only-when-testing-current-draw)
> "*

C3 & C4 are quite possibly ceramics - and the manufacturer would expect that they may be. A zener diode at the driver Vm input may help, but if this **IS** the issue then Vm and the zener would need to be of low enough voltage to ensure that critical Vm values were not reached. Generally in a PCB design good layout will help minimise these effects.

Comment: Great write up, I will take a look.

I found some other suggestions that if I do not power the driver, with 5V from the arudino, but send 24V to the driver from the PSU, it could fry the driver.

Also, it may have been that my Nema17 wasn't fully inserted into its pins, and when 24V was applied it fried the driver. 

I will run through everything and see if I can find anything else, the trouble is, I dont want to fry more drivers in my quest to understand my problem :D